# Returning values within a JSONB[] column postgres

Tags: postgresql

So I have a column within my database called divisions that lives on the company table. using a simple
SELECT divisions FROM companies;
I get the division rows of course

```
{"{\"id\": \"c88c8cf6-4b23-4575-a99f-1da966ad68a4-ceo\", \"title\": 
 \"CEO\", ... }"}
```

What I need to do is return just one field of each JSONB, title for example.

I have tried various methods to do this, the closest I can find seems to be

```
SELECT json_array_elements(divisions->>'title'::jsonb) FROM companies;
```

but this gives back the error

```
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type json
LINE 1: SELECT json_array_elements(divisions->>'title'::jsonb) FROM ...
                                           ^
DETAIL:  Token "title" is invalid.
```

any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `unnest` the PostgreSQL array first:

```
SELECT d->>'title'
FROM companies AS c
   CROSS JOIN LATERAL unnest(c.divisions) AS d(d);
```

Comment: This worked with a little bit of finageling,                        
SELECT d ->> 'title' as title
FROM companies AS c
   CROSS JOIN LATERAL unnest(c.divisions) AS d(d); got what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

`unnest()` the array column using a `CROSS JOIN`, then you can use each jsonb document normally.

```
testdb=# create table companies(company_id integer, divisions jsonb[]);
CREATE TABLE
testdb=# insert into companies select 1, ARRAY['{"title": "Foo Co"}', '{"title": "Bar Inc"}']::jsonb[];
INSERT 0 1
testdb=# insert into companies select 2, ARRAY['{"title": "Baz Ltd"}']::jsonb[];
INSERT 0 1
testdb=# select company_id, div->>'title' as title
from companies
cross join unnest(divisions) as div;
 company_id |  title  
------------+---------
          1 | Foo Co
          1 | Bar Inc
          2 | Baz Ltd
(3 rows)
```